# What is this Javascript code? Explain

Tags: javascript, facebook

This is a snippet from the Facebook Developers site.

```
<div id="info"></div>
<script>
var
  info   = document.getElementById('info'),
  update = function(response) {
    if (!response.session) {
      info.innerHTML = '<em>You must login using the controls at the top.</em>';
      return;
    }

    FB.api(
      {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid=' + response.session.uid
      },
      function(response) {
        info.innerHTML = (
          '<img src="' + response[0].pic_square + '"> ' +
          response[0].name
        );
      }
    );
  };

// update on login, logout, and once on page load
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', update);
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', update);
FB.getLoginStatus(update);
</script>
```

Above, can you please tell me what is the **update** variable, its type and how works, where does the assignment ends and who calls this function?

Secondly, what's the first argument to the **FB.api** call? What type of object is it? And I believe the second one is a callback function right?

Answer (score 1):

The update is a callback to that function. It will get executed based on what "Subscribe" does. The data being passed in is JSON. Its a plain text data representation language used to send data.

It is not SOAP-ish, its JSON. Used to pass data back and forth in javascript. It is very lightweight.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Its passing an object into FB.api that has two string members: method, and query.

Answer (score 0):

update is a function. In JavaScript you can define a function either by

```
var update = function () {
    // body
};
```

or by

```
function update() {
    // body
}
```

And as functions are first-class citizens, you can pass them as an argument, as in the FB.Event.subscribe call.

You can also define the functions inline using an anonymous function:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
    // body
});
```

The first parameter of the FB.api call is an object (a collection of key-value pairs) with two keys: 'method' and 'query' which have strings as their values.

You can read more about the JavaScript object notation (JSON) here: http://json.org/

Answer (score -1):

The first argument is just a string, looks like a namespaced soap-ish event name. The second is indeed a function, must be used as a callback of some kind.

Comment: What? `{method: 'fql.query',query: 'SELECT name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid=' + response.session.uid}` is not a string...

Comment: Its not just a string, its JSON.

Comment: Sorry, thought he meant 'fql.query' -- carry on.